# Segue from Container View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, segue

I am trying to create a segue from a container view (left VC) to a view controller (right VC). I want to be able to click on a person, who will be displayed on the left VC, and chat with him on the right VC. The thing is when I create the segue, the VC on the right instantly becomes the same size as the container view and gains the tab bar/navigation bar that the container view has but also other items that I don't need (like segmented controllers). It there any way I can connect the container view with the new VC and making the new VC an independent one? I would like to perform a segue from the base VC that holds the container view VC instead of being from the container view VC itself (in order to inherit only the tab bar and navigation bar). Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are pushing, IB will "simulate" the real behaivor (run time). Screens with same size, shows navigation bar etc.. Thanks to IB :)
2. If you want to change "the simulated size" you can, but keep in mind that it is not the real size of run time.. It only is a simulate metric
3. If you want to hide the navigation bar, do the same.
4. If you dont want that your rightVC be part of navigation controller flow, show rightVC modally or create a custom transition and show rightVC as you want.
5. Pay attention for topics: Autolayout, Size Class, Simulated Metrics

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible to perform a segue from the root VC (that holds the container) to the right VC when I tap on a cell in the container view? 
That way I would get only the tab bar and navigation bar alone, which is what I want. 
I was trying to run this code, but it is not working:

"ViewController().performSegueWithIdentifier("go", sender: ViewController())"  ____ 

"ViewController" is my root VC and "go" is the segue from there to the right VC.

Comment: Can you show all story board? Edit your answer and show it.

Comment: I understood now what you have said! I wasn't understanding the screen sizes and I tried Freeform and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Its ok.. :) I'm brazilian too .. and you can go to iosdevbr.slack.com to find many other brazilans dev. ;)